# Parsing CSV with Multiple Tables

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that contains multiple tables, e.g.:

```
##List 1##
ID,Username,Department
1,John,HR
2,Barbara,Finance
3,Jane,IT

##List 2##
ID,Username,CostCentre
1,Alex,3241
2,Jamie,3342
3,James,1234
4,Sarah,5536
```

Is there an easy way to get Powershell to recognise this as two tables? I'm currently reading line-by-line and using

```
if($row -Like "*List*")
```

(as well as some other logic) to determine the nature of the line and then write it out to one of two text files, then import those and iterate through again.

But is there a more efficient approach?

Answer (score 2):

This is not fully worked out, and I'm sure someone will come up with something much more elegant, but it is broken down into steps, so maybe it will help explain some PowerShell techniques.

```
$s=@"
##List 1##
ID,Username,Department
1,John,HR
2,Barbara,Finance
3,Jane,IT

##List 2##
ID,Username,CostCentre
1,Alex,3241
2,Jamie,3342
3,James,1234
4,Sarah,5536
"@

# break into individual lines
$s2 = ( $s -split "`r`n" ) 

# strip out blank lines
$s3 = $s2 | ? { $_ -ne "" }

# re-assemble into text blob
$s4 = $s3 -join "`r`n"

# split at tokens and skip the first, blank record
$s5 = $s4 -split "##List \d+##" | Select-Object -Skip 1

# remove blanks
$s6 = $s5 | ? { $_ -ne "" }

$s6 | % {

    # break into array of lines
    $s7 = $_ -split "`r`n"

    # remove blank lines
    $s8 = $s7 | ? { $_ -ne "" }

    $s8 | ConvertFrom-Csv

}
```